# Batch use curl/wget/aria2c with Tor and open a new Tor route for each download?

Tags: exit-relays

Can I use curl/wget/aria2c with Tor for batch downloads and appearing from a new exit node for each download? That is, I want to feed curl/wget/aria2c 1000 links to download over http(s) that each appear from a new, random, exit node (since it is random, in rare cases two downloads might appear from the same node).

It is "good enough" to create e.g., 100 circuits and then reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

mass download via tor can be somewhat tricky.
the tor network will fight against with slow conection or cut offs.
to get results you need a savy downloadmanager which can handle the cut offs and automaticaly continue the download later.
i tested FDM with acceptable results.
i did not test uget but its description is promissing.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: use Tor as a proxy with authentication and use random login+password for each stream, so it will isolate them. Also don't forget to tweak up your torrc config for a circuit isolation

Comment: How do you setup that? Link?

Comment: link for what exactly? torrc or aria?

Comment: torrc. (filler characters)

Comment: you don't need any additional setup in there - a password makes a trigger to run a separate path. Just tune your isolation https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23202/tor-stream-isolation-using-torcc