# Tor stream isolation using torcc

Tags: configuration, proxy, torsocks, socks

I use torsocks for 3 applications: IRC, SSH and Thunderbird (My Tor browser uses port 9150 from the torbrowser bundle daemon). I want to use a different tor circuit for each application. On the internet I can find a few solutions to make this work but what is safest way using torcc?

I now use the solution below which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321214/how-to-run-multiple-tor-processes-at-once-with-different-exit-ips?rq=1

```
SocksPort 9052
SocksPort 9053
```

According to the link above each socks has a different circuit but are the socks isolated in this case? Is it recommended to completely isolated from each socks? Do I need to add `IsolateDestAddr` `IsolateDestPort` and create streamgroups like here https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2010-December/000680.html with using separated Trans- and DNSPorts?

I don't want to mess up and make my tor setup less secure. What is the safest way to configure the socks?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is just use different login and password for your apps when they are connecting to **socks5s** port. However, if your app does not know authorization - you must use a separate port for it. **IsolateDestAddr** and **IsolateDestPort** are good for isolation but not a must have, but you should start with both of them enabled

Comment: In case I use Isolate I need to start with both enabled you mean?

Comment: yes, both of them must be enabled - and it will work in most of the cases. It will add a good amount of security to your setup. Only if your setup will misbehave - try it without isolation